# Could I make the strength of a magnetic field oscillate up and down, by having the voltage increase and decrease while current remains the same?

Tags: voltage, current, dc, inductor, induction

I know that because of v=ldi/dt, that if I repeatedly lower and raise the dc current of an inductor at high frequencies, the magnetic field generated will be weaker, so If i instead raised and lowered the *voltage* at high frequencies, would the magnet be workable for higher frequencies? I need to create a magnetic field about that goes up and down in strength at a frequency of 30 ghz, for an device I'm working on.

Comment: The magnetic field is induced by current, not voltage. So no, you can't change magnetic field without changing current.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but if you're asking this question then you're probably not going to be having much luck working at 30GHz (and assuming ghz is a typo, which is another giveaway).

Comment: 30GHz :-O

As previous have said, its not a trivial thing to achieve, and you need CURRENT to induce the magnetic flux. The AVERAGE current GOING INTO some push-pull type design could be made constant, but the current in your electromagnet / Coil or inductor will need to change to achieve what you wish...  and then we come back to the 'small' matter of 30 GHz

Comment: Rather than going *ham*, (aka going for the end goal), take small steps. Baby steps. Make it work at 3 kHz first. That's a very simple goal. Baby steps.

Comment: Voltage controls E field vs.  Current controls H field and the Poynting vector is the product of P=E*H while the ratio leads to impedance.

Comment: You might want to get a good book on first RF then microwave engineering, 30GHz is not trivial and the fact you are asking very basic electronics theory questions then trying to apply the answers at 30GHz is not promising. At 30GHz most of your components are in fact precisely printed geometry on an expensive precision substrate, and a lot of the off board wiring looks like small bore plumbing with silver plated tubes. What are you actually trying to achieve, there has to be some reason you think you need a 30GHz H field?

Comment: Possible digging into micro or terrawave spectroscopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that because of v=ldi/dt, that if I repeatedly lower and raise the dc current of an inductor at high frequencies, the magnetic field generated will be weaker, ...

Well, weaker and stronger. So far, so good. And by the way, if you repeatedly lower and raise a current, we'd tend to call it AC. The difference between AC and a varying DC is how fast you alter it compared to your timeframe of interest, so it's not a hard and fast distinction.

> ... so If i instead raised and lowered the voltage at high frequencies, would the magnet be workable for higher frequencies?

No, the physics stays the same, at whatever frequency. Varying the current varies the magnetic field.

But in order to vary the current, you'd need to apply a voltage to the coil. This applies at all frequencies as well.